# java regular expression extract numbers from strings with two variance

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a java program that extract stock code(s) from strings. Strings has two variances, this one:

```
Market participants are requested to note that stock with code 83199 has single counter (stock code: 83199) trading in USD.
```

or this one:

```
Market participants are requested to note that stock with code 83199 has multiple counters (stock codes: USD counter: 3199, EUR counter: 83199 and SWF counter: 9199) trading in their corresponding currency.
```

I need to extract all the numbers within the bracket and ignore those outside it. By reading answers to similar questions here, I have some success in the first variance with this pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=stock\\s{1,2}code:\\s{1,2})[0-9]*(?=\\))");
```

But don't know how to write a pattern for the second variance. I prefer to use single pattern for both if possible. I would appreciate any help on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What output you required? Please add it too in question in either case.

Comment: @Muhammad, In my post: "I need to extract all the numbers within the bracket and ignore those outside it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|\(stock)[^()\d]*(\d+)(?=[^()]*\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QKb6bP/1)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\(stock)` - either the end of the previous match or `(stock`
- `[^()\d]*` - any  0 or more chars other than `(`, `)` and digit
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits (use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to match float values as well)
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - a positive lookahead that requires any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)` immediately to the right of the current location.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/KEx2x6):

```
String s = "Market participants are requested to note that stock with code 83199 has multiple counters (stock codes: USD counter: 3199, EUR counter: 83199 and SWF counter: 9199) trading in their corresponding currency.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\G(?!^)|\\(stock)[^()\\d]*(\\d+)(?=[^()]*\\))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
} 
// => 3199, 83199, 9199
```

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are mostly the same and wont change, then use this

```
Pattern.compile("\(([^)]*)\)");
```

**Explanation:**

- `\(` - match `(` literally.
- `(...)` - capture whatever is in this
- `[^)]*` - match with everything up intil a `)`. This will ensure the
  capturing stops when the message you're trying to capture in the
  parentheses end.
- `\)` - match `)` literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HIogrt/4)

This regex means "match a string that has an opening then closing parentheses, then capture whatever's in those parentheses" so it'll work for both patterns. As long as your message always contains one set of parentheses, this'll be your best option considering its speed and simplicity.

This will match with the string and only capture what's in the parentheses in the given message, such as "stock codes: USD counter: 3199, EUR counter: 83199 and SWF counter: 9199" in your second string.

Comment: Thanks, but this one doesn't work for me since it only extract all characters within bracket.